# What is the difference between と話す and に話す

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-と

Just as the title says, I'd like to know the difference between 先生に話す
and 先生と話す, since they are both correct (if I'm wrong please correct me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

私は先生と話す means "I and the teacher have a conversation", so they talk to each other".

私は先生に話す means "I tell something to the teacher", so only I speak and the teacher listens to it.